# Greatest common divisor of a, 2b

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers where $a$ is even and such that $\gcd(2a, 2b) =
70$. Find $\gcd(a, 2b)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\gcd(2a, 2b) = 70$ then we know that $2a = 70m$ and $2b = 70n$ for some integers $m, n$ (where $\gcd(m, n) = 1$), which means that $a = 35m$. But, since $a$ is even, $a = 70k$ for some integer $k$ (where $m = 2k$).

Can you go from there?

Comment: I wanna say that we have gcd(70k,35n) = 70 implies gcd(2k,n) = 2... but I really don't see how to proceed

Comment: You don't really need to know anything about k or n except that they apparently have no factors in common. Think about what the question is asking you to find.